# Fragment's view hierarchy

Tags: android

Suppose an `Activity` only contains a single `Fragment`, and the view of the `Fragment` is created by:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Then the Fragment's root view (as returned by `onCreateView`) should be attached to the enclosing Activity.

Questions:

1. How many levels are there in the view hierarchy between an Activity and a Fragment? I mean:

   ```
   <Activity View> -> <Fragment View>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <Activity View> -> <Some ViewGroup> -> <Fragment View>
   ```

   In my test of `onCreateView`, `ViewGroup container` is `null`. Why is this?
2. If I both define in `activity_main.xml`:

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fragment_foo"
       />
   ```

   and in `fragment_foo.xml` (Suppose `ListView` is the root view element in this fragment):

   ```
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listview_foo"
       />
   ```

   Then what is **the id of the root view of the fragment**, `fragment_foo` or `listview_foo`?

   My test result is the former. Is this result expected? Does this mean we should never set the id of the root element of a fragment's layout (because it is not used anyway)?
3. Since the view hierarchy of the fragment is connected to that of the enclosing activity, both should work in finding a view in the fragment:

   ```
   getActivity().findViewById()
   ```

   and

   ```
   getView().findViewById()
   ```

   Is this correct?

Comment: could you please show the layout xml file and the code you use for putting the fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure this question out (any many other layout questions/issues) by using [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer) (run it on an emulator). It will show you the exact view structure of your Activity.